# Issue with not only, but also

Tags: grammar, word-order, conjunctions, present-perfect

I wanted to know the given 3 lines are correct or have any error, if so tell me the correct sentence

1) I have not only kicked the ball but also brought it back.

2) I not only have kicked the ball but also I have brought it back.

3) Not only I have kicked the ball but also I have brought it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) is fine.
Some other correct forms:

- I have not only kicked the ball but I have also brought it back.
- Not only have I kicked the ball but I have also brought it back.

Comment: thank you. I have posted another problem, if you solve that too I will be glad http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352053/confusion-about-singular-and-plural

Comment: you said "Some other correct forms" means the form which I used is correct

Comment: (2) and (3) would be understood but a native English speaker wouldn't say them.